# Access Pen Drive (MP3 Player) Via FileInfo?

Tags: vb.net, filesystems

I've got a Samsung Q1 attached to my computer, and I was hoping to use the FileInfo / DirectoryInfo objects to access the file on the device, however what I right click on a file in windows explorer I get a location of COMPUTER/Q1/DATACASTS/mine.mp3, and when I feed this into the DirectoryInfo object I get "Invalid network drive"

Something tells me I'm going about this the wrong way ... Is there a differant object I shoud use, or is my location string incorrect in format

Thanks in advance